# How to enable password complexity for Windows 7 Home

Tags: windows-7, passwords

After some hours of google i still did not find a solution for this question:

I'd like to enforce password complexity for users of a `Win 7 home premium` client (and PW length in second step)

- There any many hints to use gpedit for win 7 - this does not cover Home edition.
- There are hints to use regkeys ... but `Password Policy security settings are not registry keys` based on MS (even if there are keys showing the value they don't influence client behaviour) -> see XLSX WindowsServer2008R2andWindows7GroupPolicySettings
- Elevated `cmd` provides access to some `net accounts xxx` commands - but does not cover password complexity. Password length can be enforced with `net accounts /minpwlen`

Any advice appreciated

Comment: net accounts /minpwlen solves the PW-length part ... just found this

Comment: Just about everything is a registry key... GP is stored there certainly... The trick is setting the right master key for the other keys and accounts to check.